# react how to prevent default on setState without event

Tags: reactjs

Let's say you have a defined function containing a `this.setState` in a react component which is not fired by an event.

How can you do `preventDefault()` in order to keep the current scroll on the page?

I create a sandbox to illustrate this behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/damp-night-r92m5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

When groups are defined and something fire the renderer, the page scroll on top. This does not happend id groups are not defined or contain an empty array...

How can I prevent this scrolling

Comment: Can you post some of your code? What have you tried so far? How is your app structured? As it stands your question is not fleshed out enough to answer.

Comment: It sounds like something else is going on. Calling `setState` shouldn't refresh your page.

Comment: If you are controlling the scroll value in your state, then we'll definitely need to see more code in order to see how you setState. If the page just refreshes I assume you are submitting something, like a form. In which case you can still use `event.preventDefault()` at the top of that submit function. This all conjecture. More code would be most helpful.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to go along with your verbal explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your issue was nothing to do with `event` but your component is triggering render.
Based on your sandbox that you provided, you are actually declaring a new array each time the component renders. Meaning that React will assume that your `[{ id: 1, content: "group1" }, { id: 2, content: "group2" }]` is a new instance, even though all the items in the array is the same.

This line is causing your issue :

```
groups={[{ id: 1, content: "group1" }, { id: 2, content: "group2" }]}
```

### Method 1: Move your `groups` variables into state

```
const [groups, setGroups] = useState([{ id: 1, content: "group1" }, { id: 2, content: "group2" }]);
```

This way React will not rerender your `App` until you call `setState` ( In this case, `setGroups` )

### Method 2: Move your `groups` outside of your `App` function

```
const groups = [{ id: 1, content: "group1" }, { id: 2, content: "group2" }];

function App() {
 ... App Codes
}
```

In this way, React will not rerender your `App` since `groups` is not declaring within `App`.

### Method 3: Using Memoization [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) React Hook

```
const groups = useMemo(() => [{ id: 1, content: "group1" }, { id: 2, content: "group2" }], []);
```

The second argument in your `useMemo` function defines your dependencies array, setting it to empty array means that the value will never change. Hence React will not rerender your `App`.

---

In your render:

```
groups={groups}
```

Comment: I update the sandbox. Same behavior within groups declare in const:

Comment: Move it outside of `App` function, or move it into a state @lil-works